# PHP union start time and end time in multiple array

Tags: php

I have an array, I would like to union start time and end time, if the time is union get the smallest start time and biggest end time. If the time isn't union keep it.

```
[Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 09:00
                    [endTime] => 18:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 10:00
                    [endTime] => 19:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 5:00
                    [endTime] => 6:00
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 4:00
                    [endTime] => 7:00
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 12:00
                    [endTime] => 18:00
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 11:00
                    [endTime] => 21:00
                )
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 8:00
                    [endTime] => 19:00
                )
        )
```

I would like to get an array like this using PHP

```
[Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 8:00
                    [endTime] => 21:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [startTime] => 4:00
                    [endTime] => 7:00
                )

        )
```

Please help me to find a solution, thanks

Comment: I've been working on a project that has to do something very similar with times and I found that it helps to start by solving a simpler version of the problem and building it up until it does what you need.
For example: Combining many time ranges that might be overlapping is quite complex. Start simple. How you would combine just two time ranges that you know for sure are overlapping? Once you have that first piece, you can think about checking if two times need to be combined or not, or how to make this work with more than two items. Functions are going to be your friend here

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use array_column to get an array of values for specific key, and max/min it.

```
$result[] = max(array_column($array, 'endTime'));
$result[] = min(array_column($array, 'startTime'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
$array = array(
      array('starttime' => '09:00' , 'endtime' => '18:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '10:00' , 'endtime' => '19:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '05:00' , 'endtime' => '06:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '04:00' , 'endtime' => '07:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '12:00' , 'endtime' => '18:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '11:00' , 'endtime' => '21:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '08:00' , 'endtime' => '19:00')  ,
    );
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['starttime'] > $b['starttime'];
});
    foreach($array as $index => &$row){
        if(isset($array[$index-1])){
          $prev =  $array[$index-1];
          if($row['starttime'] <= $prev['starttime'] && $row['endtime'] >= $prev['endtime']){
             unset($array[$index-1]);
          } else if ($row['starttime'] >= $prev['starttime'] && $row['endtime'] <= $prev['endtime'] && $prev['endtime'] >= $row['starttime']) {
              $row['starttime'] = $prev['starttime'];
              $row['endtime'] = $prev['endtime'];
              unset($array[$index-1]);
          } else if ($row['starttime'] <= $prev['starttime'] && $row['endtime'] <= $prev['endtime'] && $prev['endtime'] >= $row['starttime']) {
              $row['endtime'] = $prev['endtime'];
              unset($array[$index-1]);
          } else if ($row['starttime'] >= $prev['starttime'] && $row['endtime'] >= $prev['endtime'] && $prev['endtime'] >= $row['starttime']) {
              $row['starttime'] = $prev['starttime'];
              unset($array[$index-1]);
          } else if ($row['starttime'] >= $prev['starttime'] && $row['endtime'] <= $prev['endtime'] && $prev['endtime'] >= $row['starttime']) {
              $row['starttime'] = $prev['starttime'];
              unset($array[$index-1]);
          }
        }
    }
    print_r($array);
```

Run this on the php sandbox
[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75adbe1e4b8518833bdf12fa898c1a3f11dd163e)